# Minimum height by css in html

Tags: html, css

I'm creating web site layout.

[image]

This is label3 css :

```
background-color:#c4efd5;
min-height:368px;
height:100%;
```

I want the label3(`<div>`) re-size to `450px` when I insert image `height=450px` and when there's no data in the box, the minimum height of label3 will be 368px. I used `min-height` but it didn't work.

Any answer will be appreciate. Thanks you.

Comment: Give label3 `display: block`

Comment: Maybe the CSS gets overwritten by another rule. Can you make a fiddle or show a link to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: **as expected** what is that suppose to mean. What went wrong?!...can't tell why it's not working if i can't see it myself. Only guess which is a waste for everyone.

Comment: what is "Label 3" a span? a div? a p tag? a h1 tag? a h2 tag? ................

Comment: Each label are <div>.

Answer (score 5):

Remove `height: 100%` it is overwriting your min-height

Comment: I tried that, but the result still the same :/

Comment: Can you post some more code? Maybe the html, if its nested in another div etc. a jsfiddle would be ideal

Answer (score 1):

What element is this being applied to? Height will have no effect on inline elements such as spans etc. Either apply it to a block level element or set display: block on the selector